# Value declared but not coming up as declared

Tags: arduino-uno, c++

```
void setup() {
// put your setup code here, to run once:
const int buttonPin2= 2;
const int buttonPin3= 3;
const int buttonPin4= 4;
const int buttonPin5= 5;
int total=0;
int wait=0;
int buttonState = 0;  
pinMode(buttonPin2, INPUT);
pinMode(buttonPin3, INPUT);
pinMode(buttonPin4, INPUT);
pinMode(buttonPin5, INPUT);
}
void loop() {
int wait=5000;
while(wait>1)
  buttonState = digitalRead(buttonPin2);  
  if(buttonState == HIGH){
    total=total+1
    wait=0
  }else{
    int wait=wait-1
  }
int wait=5000
int buttonState = 0;  
while(wait>1)
  buttonState = digitalRead(buttonPin3);  
  if(buttonState == HIGH){
     total=total+2
    wait=0
  }else{
    wait=wait-1
  }
int wait=5000
int buttonState = 0;  
while(wait>1)
  buttonState = digitalRead(buttonPin4);  
  if(buttonState == HIGH){
    total=total+4
    wait=0
  }else{
    wait=wait-1
  }
int wait=5000
int buttonState = 0;  
while(wait>1)
  buttonState = digitalRead(buttonPin5);  
  if(buttonState == HIGH){
    total=total+8
    wait=0
  }else{
    wait=wait-1
  }
int wait=5000
Serial.begin(9600)
while(0=0)
  Serial.println(total)
}
```

Comment: How about the part where you declare it? Can we see that?

Comment: Please, edit the question with the relevant code instead of posting it as a comment.

Comment: added the code to the top

Comment: You should post the whole code. The `buttonState` will work as is here. However there is the infinite loop (in `while (wait > 1) command;`

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because we cannot work with just [snippets of code](http://snippets-r-us.com/) - you must show your whole code.

Comment: Learn the meaning of "[Scope](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/scope)".

Comment: We can easily make that code compile, but whether it works (does what you want) is a different matter. What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 3):

There are many errors in this code. Below I have high-lighted some of them. Please check your C/C++ language reference(s).

```
void setup() {
// put your setup code here, to run once:
const int buttonPin2= 2;
const int buttonPin3= 3;
const int buttonPin4= 4;
const int buttonPin5= 5;
int total=0;                        <--- not used in setup()
int wait=0;                         <--- dito
int buttonState = 0;                <--- dito
pinMode(buttonPin2, INPUT);
pinMode(buttonPin3, INPUT);
pinMode(buttonPin4, INPUT);
pinMode(buttonPin5, INPUT);
}
void loop() {
int wait=5000;
while(wait>1)                             <--- missing block { ??
  buttonState = digitalRead(buttonPin2);  
  if(buttonState == HIGH){
    total=total+1                         <--- missing semi-colon ; 
    wait=0                                <--- dito
  }else{
    int wait=wait-1                       <--- local declare not used
  }
int wait=5000                             <--- illegal redeclare + semicolon
int buttonState = 0;                      <--- illegal redeclare  
while(wait>1)                             <--- missing block ; 
  buttonState = digitalRead(buttonPin3);  
  if(buttonState == HIGH){
     total=total+2                        <--- missing ;
    wait=0                                <--- and so on. 
  }else{
    wait=wait-1
  }
int wait=5000
int buttonState = 0;  
while(wait>1)
  buttonState = digitalRead(buttonPin4);  
  if(buttonState == HIGH){
    total=total+4
    wait=0
  }else{
    wait=wait-1
  }
int wait=5000
int buttonState = 0;  
while(wait>1)
  buttonState = digitalRead(buttonPin5);  
  if(buttonState == HIGH){
    total=total+8
    wait=0
  }else{
    wait=wait-1
  }
int wait=5000
Serial.begin(9600)
while(0=0)
  Serial.println(total)
}
```

Start with something much simpler and learn to master the language. Cut-and-paste programming will not help achieve any goals you might have with this sketch. You are simply wasting your time *<:)#